# didDetermineStateForRegion and didExitRegion returning false responses

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I am showing the user a local notification when they enter a beacon region, and when they exit a beacon region. The exit is the most important because I tell the user how long they dwelled in that location. I am using region monitoring because it allows me to keep track of the beacons even when the app is in the background or suspended. I am experiencing a bug where I am monitoring 3 beacons (this happens with 2 and 1, but less frequently). My phone will sleep, and I will continue to monitor for the beacons. Then, my app will wake due to didExitRegion for one of the beacons, even though all 3 beacons are sitting face up on the same desk as my phone. It is a different beacon each time, so I have ruled our signal strength. Then, once the app is awake, it rediscovers the beacon and immediately re enters (because it never left the signal in the first place). I am detecting the signals with an android device at the same time, and the beacons are broadcasting the whole time, so the iPhone should not be losing these signals, especially not for a long enough time to consider it an exit.

I tried to remedy this by using

```
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:region];
```

However, in these situations this will return state 2, which is CLRegionStateOutside.

How should I get around this? Has anyone had a similar experience. I should be able to dwell in a beacon region for 1 minute or 1 hour and only get an exit when the beacon is undetected for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Verify this happens with multiple iOS devices.  It is possible that the iOS device has a hardware problem such that it has weaker Bluetooth LE reception, or picks up more radio noise.  I have never seen this myself, but I have heard reports of others who insist they have seen it on some iOS devices.
- Check the signal level received by the iOS device and the Android device by ranging the beacon using an app like Locate for [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en).  The signal levels should be similar on both devices.   A strong signal will have an RSSI of about -60 or less negative.  A weak signal will have an RSSI of about -100 or more negative.  If you have a weak signal, it may cause intermittent detection losses because radio noise will sometimes prevent packets from being received properly.  If you can configure your beacons to increase their transmitter power level, do so.
- With the Locate app in the foreground, range the beacon to check the signal level and rotate it at different angles.  Some beacons have antenna patterns that are much weaker on one side.  You may find that the orientation gives a much weaker signal, and again, a weak signal can cause dropouts.
- Check the specs or configuration settings of your beacon to see how often your beacons are transmitting.  Beacons that are configured to transmit rarely to conserve battery (e.g. once every 5 seconds) are more likely to cause this situation because it only takes 6 missed packets in a row (rare but possible) to cause a region exit.

One other possibility is that there is an unusual amount of radio noise periodically in your vicinity in the Bluetooth frequency range.  This is unlikely, but I have seen it before.  I live across the street from a U.S. Marine installation with powerful antennas, and at home I often get much higher packet CRC error rates than I do in the office.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The 6 missed packets is what is causing this. I set up a test by having 1 phone log the RSSIs while another monitored. The "false exit" occurred when I got 6 RSSIs at -95 and lower (or 0) in a row. Specifically I got -96, 0, -95, 0, -96, 0.  Can this be resolved by decreasing the advertising interval, or is there some way to make this 6 missed packets more lenient?

Comment: This suggests to me that the device that exited the region is not receiving the signals as strongly as the one that was ranging.  Any detection no matter how weak will keep an in region status, so the existing phone must have detected nothing in 30 seconds for one of the reasons I described.  Yes, increasing broadcast rate and transmitter power both might help, as it provides more packets to detect and at a stronger signal.